# Can you reuse results of tests that have already been run in other nested feature files?

Tags: caching, resultset, karate

I'm new to the Karate Framework :)

I am currently looking at https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-demo/src/test/java/demo/callnested/CallNestedRunner.java and I have already thought of a structure to do my tests.
I would like to stick with karate to do feature tests but by using nested feature files. What I'm talking about is this:

```
Project
| - Features
| | - Feature1.feature
| | - Feature2.feature
| - Tests
| | - Test01.feature
```

so Feature1.feature and Feature2.feature have the following code:

```
Scenario: Test01: This is a common test
When def result = call read('classpath:Project/Tests/Test01.feature')
Then match result.testStatus == 'pass'
```

so when I run karate, I notice that it runs it two times, once for each nested call.

So my question is, is there a way to reuse the result of the tests such that if it has already been run once, it will not run it again but instead reuse the results from the previous one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for "hooks", so refer the docs: https://github.com/intuit/karate#hooks

So I think this pattern is what you are looking for:

```
Background:
* def result = callonce read('classpath:Project/Tests/Test01.feature')

Scenario:
* match result.testStatus == 'pass'
```

Comment: Hmmmm, I don't think putting it in the Background will be my take, as I plan to call multiple different test files as well. I was looking around a few minutes ago and found `karate.callSingle` and found that it also works for parallel runners and It worked wonders!

Answer (score 1):

I used [Karate.callSingle](https://github.com/intuit/karate#karate-callsingle). Also @PeterThomas' answer regarding [Karate Hooks](https://github.com/intuit/karate#hooks) would help

Feature1.feature, Feature2.feature

```
Scenario: Test01: This is a common test
When def result = karate.callSingle('classpath:Project/Tests/Test01.feature')
Then match result.testStatus == 'pass'
```

this way, if you have multiple other nested calls you can add them up in the pattern as above